# Is firebase functions http requests secure

Tags: firebase, http, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a project and i wanted to know if firebase fucntion http requests are secure. In short, if i pass data using post, will other people be able to listen to data within the request and if so how can i prevent it

Answer (score 1):

As long as the url starts with "https", and the client isn't accepting incorrect certificates, then it's secure.